# Deploying PWA on smartphone without going through the browser

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, mdm

I created a PWA app that opens on my smartphone by clicking the icon in "browser window" mode, therefore without a header or other browser element, just the web page. However, it only works after switching to the browser and following the "add to home screen" or "install app" procedure.

I need to deploy it to all company phones via "MDM Mobile device management", but I would like it to open directly via the icon, without going through the browser via the "install app" procedure.

This is to avoid the user having to take multiple steps to create the launch icon.

It's possible? For example, by setting a particular link of the web app on MDM Mobile device management? So that you open the app in "browser window" mode? without going through the browser via the "install app" procedure?

Thank you